# Bluemix services limit exceeded

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to create any new service in Bluemix but I'm always getting the message: 'You have exceeded your organization's services limit'. However, on Services & API tile I have: '6/10 Used' so it seems that's not the problem. If I remove any service I can create a new one. But as soon as I get 6/10 used, I cannot create new ones. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you paste " cf org <your_org_name> ? "

Comment: I was trying to create them from Bluemix web. But I tried with CF cli. It asked me to login, so I used cf login, then it asked me for an API endpoint, what does it mean?

Comment: cf api api.ng.bluemix.net if you are in US-SOUTH region --- cf api api.eu-gb.bluemix.net if you are in UK region

Comment: domains: mybluemix.net
quota: q2GB (2048M memory limit, 2048M instance memory limit, 500 routes, 10 services, paid services allowed, unlimited app instance limit)

Comment: Are you the only member in your organization? Do you have more than one space?

Comment: No, there're more members and three spaces, but I have not access to them. But I'm seeing 6/10 services used, those 6 are not used by me, but it seems that there's quota available...

Comment: Ruben, reading the responses above, I suppose you have some configuration on your ORG & Spaces.
If you provide us your Bluemix userID (the email you have registered you account with) and the ORG name we could have a look
If you prefer (due to privacy reasons) you could open a chat with one of us (me or @vmovva or @crescenzo-migliaccio)

Answer (score 1):

I have also got similar issue, to view my services I did change my workspace Region as "US South" then it shows all my services. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, Have you ever come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994362/inactive-tts-not-upgrading-or-reseting) situation when you exceed your monthly quota limit?